# warning: no previous prototype for... C++

Tags: c++

Trying to get a clean compile here, but I get this:

```
recorders/r5000/r5k_sat.c:179:6: warning: no previous prototype for ‘sat_find_chname’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 void sat_find_chname(unsigned char *buf, struct sids *sids, unsigned int size) {
```

When I put in r5000_internal.h (the header file for r5k_sat.c):

```
void sat_find_chname(unsigned char *buf, struct sids *sids, unsigned int size)
```

... I get:  https://pastee.org/3u3dh
(forum won't allow me to post it here)

Comment: The error messages are quite clear: you need a declaration of `struct sids` before the function declaration.

Comment: I think understand what you mean, thanks Mike.  qwrrty this is the very last compile warning I'm getting.  I don't have to fix this, just as I didn't have to fix half of the almost a hundred errors I've gotten and corrected through this saga, but I'd like it to be right and I'd like to learn something.  You and Lightness may have forgotten that, you too were once a n00b and, you too were once out of your depth.  Want to know Civil Law?  I can help you there.

Comment: I am here to learn something new, and although this is my last error, thanks to the able help I have gotten here I can see that this is attainable.  True, I lack the book learning at this point, but that's something that can be fixed.  What I lack in education in C++, I make up for in persistence.  And yes, this is C++.  And STFU about this not being a forum Lightness.  Take out your frustrations somewhere else.

Comment: It's not wise to talk to people that way here. I suggest you edit your last comment and apologize, if you want to continue to benefit from the advice of experts like Lightness.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I am not interested in negativity from those with the attitude of Lightness.  I'll throw it right back in their face.  I've noticed quite a few here see fit to Beat Up On The N00b, and as a attorney that is offensive.  Maybe it's how you people live, IDK.  Please also know that I am unable to edit my comments 5 minutes after they're posted, even if I were so inclined.  In any case my last error is now resolved, thanks to Mike.  I don't see any method to credit him, or I would.  See I don't need much help, but it seems to reflexively inflame a few for some reason.